# Why is Array.prototype.push faster than variable declaration

Tags: javascript, jsperf

I ran the following jsperf https://jsperf.com/push-vs-define-anaoum

and found out that push in this case :

```
var a = [];
a.push([1,2,3]);
a.push(["a","b","c"]);
```

is faster than just declaring a with the subarrays inside :

```
var a = [
  [1,2,3],
  ["a","b","c"]
];
```

Could anyone please tell me why or point me in the right documentation?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Which browser did you use? I just tried in Edge and the `push` came out 20% slower.

Comment: @KirkLarkin  Chrome 60.0.3112 / Windows 7 0.0.0

Comment: `.push()` Firefox 55 on Windows 10 came out 23% slower but Chrome 61 came out 75% faster (similar results).

Comment: @Pluto yeah, I wouldn't say I'm surprised but I would still love to read documentation or articles on the subject. Optimization is very important to me

Comment: for me on Chrome 61 push is about 6.5 times faster too on jsperf.com, but slower on http://jsben.ch, so depends on how it's measured too

Answer (score 1):

For me declaring a with sub arrays went faster than push :)

I think it depends on computer's/device's components

[image: My example]

Comment: I'm using Chrome 60.0.3112 / Windows 7 0.0.0